# Can you find the error in this HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please help me to find the error? This code doesn't work and I don't understand why. I want to sort my list by price.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="LowToHigh()">Low To High</button>

    <ul id="list1">
        <li data-price="25" data-quality="8">Product1</li>
        <li data-price="9" data-quality="9">Product2</li>
        <li data-price="17" data-quality="6">Product3</li>
    </ul>

<SCRIPT>
function LowToHigh() 
{
$('#list1 li').sort(sort_li).appendTo('#list1');
    function sort_li(a, b) {
    var price1 = Number($(a).data('price'))
    var price2 = Number($(b).data('price'))
        if (price1 < price2) {return -1}
        else {
            if (price1 > price2) {return +1}
            else {return 0}
    }}
}
</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with it, if you intend to sort by data-price. Have you included jQuery in the head?

Comment: You don't have jquery in your code, <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: No, I haven't. How can I do this?

Comment: Add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before the closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks to both, but it doesn't work, maybe there is another error that I haven't noticed?

Comment: Now I've added it before tag <html> and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this way to add `jquery` to your code with `<script>` tag and see your sorting is working fine from **LowToHigh** Order.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="LowToHigh()">Low To High</button>

    <ul id="list1">
        <li data-price="25" data-quality="8">Product1</li>
        <li data-price="9" data-quality="9">Product2</li>
        <li data-price="17" data-quality="6">Product3</li>
    </ul>

<script>
function LowToHigh() 
{
$('#list1 li').sort(sort_li).appendTo('#list1');
    function sort_li(a, b) {
    var price1 = Number($(a).data('price'))
    var price2 = Number($(b).data('price'))
        if (price1 < price2) {return -1}
        else {
            if (price1 > price2) {return +1}
            else {return 0}
    }}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've added it before tag <html> and it works

Comment: @MarcoP glad it helps you some how. By the way you can mark it as an accepted answer :) with green tick

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery in your `<head></head>` block:

```html
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've added it in the <head></head> block but it didn't work. I've added it above <html> and it worked, I don't know why.